# Why does the following casting with method reference not produce a compilation error?

Tags: java, java-8

```
public class SomeClass{

    public static int someFunction(int a) {
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Consumer<Integer> c = SomeClass::someFunction; 
    }
}
```

I'm not getting why: `Consumer<Integer> c = SomeClass::someFunction;`
is not producing a compilation error, since the function someFunction is a method with return value, and Consumer is representing methods with no return value

Comment: You can use `SomeClass::someFunction` as a consumer. It will happily consume an integer. You just won't be able to capture the return value. Why should it be a compile error?

Comment: It's just like how you can call a value-bearing method as a statement and ignore the return value.  (There are some methods (like `List.add()`) that many people don't even realize returns a value; if you couldn't convert `list::add` to a `Consumer<T>`, that would be really irritating.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-LambdaBody):

> If the body of a lambda is a statement expression (that is, an
>   expression that would be allowed to stand alone as a statement), it is
>   compatible with a void-producing function type; **any result is simply
>   discarded.**

Same is true for method references.

It's more flexible that way. Suppose it was a compiler error to not use a return value when you called a method normally - that would be *incredibly annoying*. You'd end up having to use fake variables you didn't care about in some cases.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static int someFunction(int a) {
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        someFunction(3); // "error" - ignoring return type
        int unused = someFunction(3); // "success"
    }
}
```

If you want a the full formal definition of what is acceptable, see [15.13.2. Type of a Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.2).

Answer (score 12):

This is called special `void compatibility rule`. For example how many times have you actually cared about `List#add` return type? Even if it does return `true/false`.

Pretty much the same thing here, you can invoke a method, but ignore its result. If you re-write your consumer as a lambda expression, it makes more sense:

```
Consumer<Integer> c = x -> {
   SomeClass.someFunction(x);
   return;     
}
```

If I remember correctly from the JLS there are only some types that are allowed for this.

```
 increment/decrement operations
 method invocation
 assignment 
 instance creation
```